# component to theme a StringGrid like the ThemedDBGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, tstringgrid

Exist  any similar component to theme a stringrid like the [ThemedDBGrid](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2009/01/new-themeddbgrid-unit-version/)  component compatible with delphi 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you could take the source from ThemedDBGrid and re-work it for a stringgrid? Or you could use a DBGrid and wrap your strings up so that they can be accessed through a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

TMSSoftware's Advanced String Grid is pretty popular:

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advgrid.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at skinning components that skin the built in grid, such as:
http://www.almdev.com/